# Blogspot blog only show 50 images per page

Tags: blogger

My blog (http://ngamanhdep.blogspot.com) only shows 50 images per page though I set number of posts per page to 60.

Is 50 the maximum limit or either can I increase the number of images or is there another way to show many images (about 100) per page?

Answer (score 1):

That is most probably a result of a feature called auto-pagiation, which Blogger users to manage the load on its servers:   Remember you are not paying for Blogger, so this means you have to share whatever resources they make available.

There is no way to turn it off.

You may have some success if you use lower-resolution picture - which would have good spin off impacts on how long pages take to load for your visitors, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is [limitation on blogger](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/42348?hl=en).

But you can show up more than 50 images per page with the help of Thumbnail, just upload mini thumbnail in your blogger like this.

```
<a href="Filename.jpg"  target="_blank"><img src="Thumbnail-Filename.jpg"  alt="this is alt text" /></a>
```

1) href=""
This is your main image URL

2)target="_blank"
By setting this attributes our Filename.jpg will open in new tab of browser.

3)Img src=""
Here enter your compressed images URL link in source.

So by adding this html code you will see a src images in blogger page, and whenever people click on it, then they will see a original image in new tab of browser.

Actually using this technique you can load your blogger page more quickly because it is display only src images and that is less in size. ( you can use third party tool to compress your image size, You can also use Microsoft picture manager for that)

With the help of [schema](http://schema.org/ImageObject) you can optimize your images in best way.